# UIRoot does not exist in the clr-namespace?

Tags: c#, xaml, xml-namespaces

I am using an external library which generates an class for UI in my game from XAML, everything generates fine and it's working as intended except for one part. It says the Root element does not exist in the namespace and thus I cannot use the designer, the creator of the library himself doesn't even know why it is doing this, it works fine for him.

```
<!--ek:UIRoot was not found/ does not exist in the namespace-->

<ek:UIRoot 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:ek="clr-namespace:EmptyKeys.UserInterface.Designer;assembly=EmptyKeys.UserInterface.Designer" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" Grid.Row="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="This is EmptyKeys In monogame" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</ek:UIRoot>
```

And yet it does
[image: Definitely exists in the namespace]
The project is .net4.5 and anycpu the same as what the library is built on and i've rebuild the solution many times. (those were the solutions to similar issues)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you missing @Register directive?

Comment: Na it was a blocked dll... windows man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to unblock the dll because it came from another computer
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile.aspx

the example is a zip but it applies the same for dlls